# Extract components of long id returned via gridView.setOnItemClick?

Tags: android

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image" + position " selected", Toast.LENGTH_Short).show();
    }
```

Regarding the solution to my recent problem (ArrayList and GridView), *long id* holds all the data of 1 line of the database 
(in this case just _ID and _DATA) which I need. I assume that (in imageAdapter class) *getCursor.getInt(0)* refers to the _ID 
column 0 and *getCursor.getInt(1)* to the _DATA one, so how do I reference that here in the *gridView.setOnItemClick?* After all, 
*position* gives the image clicked so *id* must hold something relating to it. Does this depend on what value (in ImageAdapter class) *public long getItemId* returns?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after many random attempts. Adjust ImageAdapter class as below:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    getCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return getCursor.getString(1);   //--- not default return position!
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    getCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    id = getCursor.getLong(0);
    return id;
}
```

This returns the correct values that can be used in onItemClickListener

```
long column = myAdapter.getItemId(position); //--- long value of the _ID column.
String data = myAdapter.getItem(position);   //--- String value of _DATA column.
```

So what is the returned long id *(in OnItemClick)* providing?